# Script works when it's a file on same server, but not when on remote server

Tags: javascript, html

https://repl.it/KghU/1 - The javascript (index2.js) will run if the script src is set to "index2.js" but not when the src is set to the same script on github.gist. What gives?

Comment: posst your code here

Comment: Possibly because gist is serving the script with a content-type of text/pain.

Answer (score 0):

They probably have a same-origin policy in place for cross-domain requests. Here's a good article explaining this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS